# Proper way to complete an rxjs observable interval?

Tags: rxjs, observable

My scenario is that I add a record set to a host zone via aws sdk.  When adding a record set, the aws sdk has a `GetChange` call that can be used to get that status.  Here is the code I am currently doing:

```
  this._adminService.registerDomain(caseWebsiteUrl.Url).
    subscribe(id => {
      return Observable.interval(5000).flatMap(() => {
        return this._adminService.getChange(id);
      }).
        takeWhile((s) => s.ChangeInfo.Status.Value !== 'INSYNC').subscribe(
        () => {

        },
        () => {

        },
        () => this.urlStatus = 'fa fa-check');

    });
```

In the above code, I want to call `registerDomain` and after that has been successful, I want to call `getChange` every `5 seconds` until the `Status.Value !== 'INSYNC'`

A few questions:

1. What is flatMap doing?
2. Is it possible to do this without 2 subscribe calls?
3. If I don't need the next or error callbacks, but I need the complete, is it necessary to declare empty bodies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatmap aka MergeMap will flatten higher order observables. Thus `Observable<Observable<T>> => Observable<T>`.

The subscribe inside subscribe is a code smell and can and should be refactored. If you do not need the error/complete handlers you do not need to pass those. For instance:

```js
function registerDomain(caseWebsiteUrl) {
  return this._adminService.registerDomain(caseWebsiteUrl.Url)
      .concatMap(registerId => Observable.interval(5000)
          .mergeMap(() => this._adminService.getChange(registerId))
          .takeWhile((info) => info.ChangeInfo.Status.Value !== 'INSYNC'))
}
registerDomain.subscribe(res => console.log('res:'+res));
```

This works based on the assumption and limitations that:

- `registerDomain()` returns an Observable which completes
- `getChange()` will eventually return 'INSYNC'
- No error handling has been added (for instance a timeout after 30 seconds? Retry if `registerDomain()` fails?)

Comment: How should I refactor the subscribe?  I need complete. I do not need next and error.

Comment: I have added a refactor example

Comment: Can you elaborate on concatMap and mergeMap?